# Slurm Script to stagger start of processes

Tags: bash, jobs, slurm

I am wondering how to use the --begin command in Slurm to stagger the start of each array element.

I have tried the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --time=48:00:00
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=16g
#SBATCH --tmp=16g
#SBATCH --output=job-%j.out
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --array=1-1000
#SBATCH --begin=now+${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}seconds

module load matlab/R2021a

matlab -r "JobIndex=$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID;datascript;exit;"
```

However, this has the following error:

```
Invalid time specification (pos=3): now+${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}seconds
sbatch: error: Invalid --begin specification
```

Is there something wrong with my --begin line? How can I fix this error?

Comment: The variable `SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID` will be defined when the job runs, but when you are launching it, it is either read as-is or interpreted in the current environment, neither option is what you are looking for. This should be equivalent to removing the `--begin` parameter from inside the script and using it in the command line: `sbatch --begin... <script>`.